# Getting the color of a pixel

Tags: java, colors, pixel

Is it possible to load an image onto a buffered image and then get the color of that pixel? Also, is it possible to assign values of an RBG color to a variable? For example, if a picture, at a specific pixel 5, 5 has a color (20, 50, 200) is it possible to get that value and then assign x = R(20), y = G(50) and z = B(200)?

Comment: Yes, it's all very possible, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21444587/getting-pixel-rgb-from-a-bufferedimage-from-the-mouses-x-and-y-possition/21445320#21445320) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537867/java-get-the-rgba-from-a-buffered-image-as-an-array-of-integer/27538044#27538044)

Comment: Oh and [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) might help as well