# Java - Put an image as a byte[] on the screen

Tags: java, graphics

I need to put on the screen, in the simplest way possible, an image buffer in the form of a byte[] where bytes <s>0-3 are the RGBA</s> *using RGB in this case so bytes 0-2* of one pixel, and so on. I can't figure out how to do this, and the only information I could find is on loading the image from a file -- totally not something I want to potentially be doing 60 times per second!

So, how can I do this?

**EDIT: Adding some very much needed background.**

I am creating my own 2D graphics library, which may seem redundant, but I'm doing this because I feel the Graphics2D API is unsuitable for some applications (and not easily extendable as far as I can tell), especially the game project I am writing this library for.

The basic element of this library is my Canvas class which serves as the thing which my Drawable objects will be rendered onto. It stores its data, depending on which variant is being used, in either an RGB, RGBA or monochrome formatted array of bytes. I chose this method because I believe it allows for some much faster rendering operations. (Each Drawable must have a method which takes a Canvas and renders the object onto it, and this process can include directly writing to the buffer.)

What I'm trying to do in the game is to take those finished Canvas frames and put them onto a JFrame or something like that.

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at [`java.awt.Color(int, boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#%3Cinit%3E(int,boolean)) which can unpack a `rgba` packed value and present it as `Color` object

Comment: Using `Color` for each pixel like this might be a little heavy handed.  You could cache the results, but if you're up for a little experimenting, you can unpack the value manually, [see some of the other answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537867/java-get-the-rgba-from-a-buffered-image-as-an-array-of-integer) for some more ideas

Comment: *"and the only information I could find is on loading the image from a file"* - Well, that raises the question of, why would you re-load the image?  One assumes it's not changing

Comment: @MadProgrammer I plan to change it many times per second...

Comment: Ok, curios why you'd only use a byte[] array and not use something like `BufferedImage`, which would generally be faster to paint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the alpha channel you could just use `setRGB(int startX, int startY, int w, int h, int[] rgbArray, int offset, int scansize)`.

Like:

```
BufferedImage myImage = new BufferedImage(...);
myImage.setRGB(...); //insert here your byte array
```

PS you have to delete and remove the *alpha* bytes out of your array first

Like so:

```
for(int i = 0, j = 0; i++; i < RGBA.length){
    if(((i + 1) % 4) == 0) continue;
    //if((i % 4) == 3) continue; //this would also work
    RGB[j] = RGBA[i];
    j++;
}
```

Comment: Oh right, I plan to only display RGB arrays to the screen, the RGBA's are for layering. I guess I'll have to do some performance testing with this method.

Comment: IT WORKS! And with a delightful amount of performance. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hU5sJsM-i7M

Comment: You could probably improve performance by round about 100% when you write your own `setRGB(...)`, which is able to use RGBA-arrays as input. Btw nice demo